# Google Analytics is not showing historical data from before the view was created

Tags: google-analytics

I have a question with regard to what data is shown on GA.

Background, I recently set up a new view with filters for a new sub-domain. I have been advised that the Google Tracking code was implemented a while ago (at least a month) however, I am only seeing data from the date that I created the view.

Should the data be available from the point that the tracking was implemented?

Also, I just noticed that the Universal tag was implemented by the developers, however in analytics, the code is Global site tag. Would that be a conflict and reason for missing data?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us your Google analytics tracking code so we could see if there might be a problem with it

Comment: I am confident the tracking code is correct (as it is picking up data) I believe clarification on the questions, will highlight the conversation I need to have with the developers 1) Should the data be available from the point that the tracking was implemented? and 2) would there be a conflict to using universal tag when GA is indication the GTM tag instead?

Answer (score 4):

Views will only report data going forward from the date they are created, not historical data.

eta - Cant find the specific info in the GA Help Center docs however Google's video on youtube, which is part of the Analytics Academy learning material does cover it
https://youtu.be/quVksNTcbiA?t=3m4s

In regards to the tagging.. Global Site Tag gtag.js is composed of two pieces of script, both associated with the GA tracking id.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/

When checking the site in Google Tag Assistant (GTA), it will show two tags.
One for gtag.js the other for Universal Analytics.
Provided GTA shows it is only firing one pageview for Universal Analytics, then all should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you Bronwyn, this is really helpful, really appreciate your input!